# Redirect Opencart to different theme for mobile

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect, opencart

I am creating a seperate opencart theme for displaying on smaller screen resolutions.

I am not editing the existing theme to make it responsive.

Is there a way to detect the device/screen width and switch the theme to the mobile one?

Cheers, Sam

Comment: Can't we use css3 media queries?

Comment: There are plenty of extensions that do this already on the extension store. Search for mobile frameworks. You should be able to integrate your theme into one of those

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

There is a extension that does the trick: [HERE](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=856&filter_search=mobile%20switch)